# Freezing an intermediate layer in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Suppose I have a simple Neural Network designed as:

```
lin0 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
lin1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
lin2 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
```

My aim is to freeze the second layer, keeping the weight updating if the first and in the third one.

I have tried doing

```
x = lin0(x)
with torch.no_grad():    
    x = lin1(x)
x = lin2(x)
```

in the forward function, that should freezes all the parameters of 'lin1'. However, I am wondering if the back propagation is still reaching the first layer, and in case, how it updates the weights. Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tried 2 things:

1. Like you said, using torch.no_grad() on the one layer you want to not change parameters for while training
2. Set the layer.required_grad to False

In the first case, the parameter values didn't change for layer 0 and layer 1. In the second case, however, the parameters didn't change only for layer 1 -- just like you wanted. I think when we use torch.no_grad(), the entire model stops right there when it comes to updating parameters.

P.S: I just tracked the values of each layers parameters using the .parameter() function available in pytorch. Try it yourself and let me know!

First instance:

Model:

```
    class model(torch.nn.Module):

      def __init__(self):
    
          super(model,self).__init__()
          self.lin0 = nn.Linear(1,2)
          self.lin1 = nn.Linear(2,2)
          self.lin2 = nn.Linear(2,10)
    
      def forward(self,x):
   
          x = self.lin0(x)
          with torch.no_grad():
             x = self.lin1(x)
          x = self.lin2(x)

  
    
          return x

      model = model()
```

Second Instance:

```
    class model(torch.nn.Module):

       def __init__(self):
    
           super(model,self).__init__()
           self.lin0 = nn.Linear(1,2)
           self.lin1 = nn.Linear(2,2)
           self.lin2 = nn.Linear(2,10)
    
       def forward(self,x):
   
           x = self.lin0(x)
  
           x = self.lin1(x)
           x = self.lin2(x)

  
    
       return x

    model = model()
    model.lin1.weight.requires_grad = False
    model.lin1.bias.requires_grad = False
```

Comment: Thank you, that's was I was suspecting, but I didn't have idea on how to check it

Comment: @earnest Just try passing a random tensor through your model; that should generally help.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct; in the forward pass, torch.no_grad() will prevent the computation of gradients for the frozen layer (lin1).
However, in the backward pass, gradients will still flow through lin1, but the optimizer won't update its parameters because they are marked as not requiring gradients.